# Count value db Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

I would like to calculate the apartments in the project according to the floor. How could I do that?

This is db

```
$table->id();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('project_building_id')->nullable();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('project_model_id');
$table->string('apartment_number')->nullable();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('level_id')->nullable();
```

Leve_id is based on the floor But I would like that depending on project_model_id

E.g: I have a 6-story building. Those 6 floors each assigned apartments. I would like to calculate the apartments according to the floor. For example for the 6th floor x apartments. I have in that db, from what you saw, level_id which holds the role of floor. And Items is the db where the apartments are. I want to send these values ​​in the view that is written in the view and I wouldn't want to loop for that.

Comment: What code you have written so far to calculate the count?

Comment: $itemsCount = DB::table('items')->distinct('level_id')->count();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a `group by`, I have added a sample query below, Because without proper table description and exact output requirement its hard to provide a correct answer, But the following should give you a direction.

```
$itemsCount = DB::table('items')
->groupby('level_id')
->selectRaw('level_id, count(*) as apartment_count');
```

you should be able to get an output similar to the following

```
+----------+-----------------+
| level_id | apartment_count |
+----------+-----------------+
|        0 |               1 |
|        1 |              10 |
|        2 |               4 |
+----------+-----------------+
```